# memory_limit not work

Tags: php, memory-limit

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 104857600 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 32345609 bytes)

It mean I need 137203209 bytes memory limit to run my php script.
I got this error although I have the following code in the script.

```
 ini_set('memory_limit', 268435456); # 256 MB
```

The script is on my shared hosting server. I don't have access to **php.ini**.
The `memory_limit` did work for other scripts in the same hosting server.

When I checked phpinfo() of my server, I see these

> suhosin.memory_limit - 128
>   memory_limit - 100M

My script definitely needs more than 128M because it is a mail sending script with large file attachment.

Comment: `phpinfo();` and check if your `ini_set` changed it. There is a chance  (I'd say 99%) you're not allowed to do that.

Comment: Are you sure you need that much memory? If you do, maybe you shouldn't be on shared hosting. Also keep in mind that bugs on your code (like an infinite loop) can also cause that error, by exhausting all available memory.

Comment: @bfavaretto: no infinite loop actually. I have successfully run the script in my localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`suhosin.memory_limit - 128` does not allow you to increase memory limit higher that 128mb, set it to 268435456 to be allowed to increase memory_limit up to 256Mb. I doubt you can do it on a shared hosting, though, because you need an access to suhosin ini file (you can not do something like `ini_set('suhosin.memory_limit', 268435456);`).

[`More about suhosin.memory_limit`](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.memory_limit)

Comment: @SithuKyaw It's rare that a script should use more than 128M unless you're doing something super heavy (image processing, etc)

Comment: @Sithu Kyaw, it depends :) E.g. I have a script which defines all permutations of ~30 words - it consumes a lot of memory (close to 256Mb) because I'm getting back about 25k rows and, before joined with " ", each word remains in array separately from other words. Of course, I can optimize it by appending each permutation calculation to a file for example, but I'm just too lazy. I could optimize it if this script worked on a production server to not affect other php processes so they crash because of memory lack. While I don't have to, I don't bother myself to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You're on a shared host, and shared hosts almost never let you using the `ini_set('memory_limit',XXX)` functions (otherwise everyone would always try to grab the whole server memory and lock up the whole server). Check `phpinfo()` to see if safe-mode is on... it probably is.

Also, side-note: if you want to set the memory limit to 256MB in any case, you can just use the:

ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');

notation instead of writing out the whole integer.

Comment: I see safe-mode is off in my server.